# NameError in a Class Within a Other Class

Tags: python, class, nameerror

In this program I was trying to make a class called Human and inside of it have classes that represent different attributes of a Human:

```
class Human:       
        class Health:
            def __init__(self):
                self.thirst = 24
                self.hunger = 36
                self.howSleepy = 48
        class Ginetics:
            def __init__(self, spawnCoordinates, parentM, parentF, isMale):
                self.spawnCoordinates = coordinates
                self.parentM = parentM 
                self.parentF = parentF 
                self.isMale = isMale
                self.kids = [[]]
        class General:
            def __init__(self, birthday):    
                self.birthday = birthday

        def __init__(self, spawnCoordinates, parentM, parentF, isMale, birthday):
            self.Health = Health()
            self.Genetics = Genetics(spawnCoordinates, parentM, parentF, isMale)
            self.General = General(birthday)
```

But when I run this...

```
hum1 = Human((500,500), "Dan", "Lisa", True, 120)
```

It gives me this error:

```
NameError: name 'Health' is not defined
```

Comment: Try `Human.Health()` instead of `Health()`

Comment: You need to access the outer class first in order to access the inner ones, check this tutorial, it explains everything: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/inner-classes-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate your classes instead of nesting them, there is no benefit of doing so and it makes your code less readable.

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, spawnCoordinates, parentM, parentF, isMale, birthday):
        self.Health = Health()
        self.Genetics = Genetics(spawnCoordinates, parentM, parentF, isMale)
        self.General = General(birthday)

class Health:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thirst = 24
        self.hunger = 36
        self.howSleepy = 48

class Genetics:
    def __init__(self, spawnCoordinates, parentM, parentF, isMale):
        self.spawnCoordinates = spawnCoordinates
        self.parentM = parentM 
        self.parentF = parentF 
        self.isMale = isMale
        self.kids = [[]]

class General:
    def __init__(self, birthday):
        self.birthday = birthday


hum = Human((500, 500), "Dan", "Lisa", True, 120)
print(hum.General.birthday)
```

Output:

```
120
```

Answer (score 0):

`Health` et al. are not global variables; they are class attributes. You would have to write `self.Health = Human.Health()`.

However, nested classes typically are not used in Python.  The *intent* may be to only use `Health` with an instance of `Human`, but nothing about its definition is inherently tied to `Human`. Just declare it globally:

```
class Health:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thirst = 24
        self.hunger = 36
        self.howSleepy = 48


...


class Human:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.health = Health()
        ...
```